# Deletion in binary search tree in C

Tags: c, linked-list, binary-tree

My linked list structure is

```
typedef struct ll
{
 int data;
 struct ll *left;
 struct ll *right;
}node;
```

My function for deleting is

```
void delete(node **parent,node **root,int n)
{
 if((*root)==NULL) //if tree is empty then return
 {
  printf("No tree\n");
  return;
 }
 else
 {
   if(((*root)->data)==n)
  {
   free(*root);
   return;  // if head is the node to be deleted
  }
  else if(((*root)->data)<n)
  {
   (*parent)=(*root);
   (*root)=(*root)->right;
  }
  else(((*root)->data)>n);
  {
   (*parent)=(*root);
   (*root)=(*root)->left;
  }
   while((*root)!=NULL)
   {
    if(((*root)->data)==n)
    {      
     break;
    }
    (*parent)=(*root);
    if(((*root)->data)>n)
    (*root)=(*root)->left;
    else
    (*root)=(*root)->right;
   }
 }
 if(((*root)->left)==NULL && ((*root)->left)==NULL) //both children are NULL
 {
  del_a(parent,root);
 }
 else if(((*root)->left)==NULL && ((*root)->left)!=NULL)// only one child is NULL
 {
  del_b(parent,root);
 }
 else if(((*root)->left)!=NULL && ((*root)->left)==NULL)// only one child is NULL
 {
  del_b(parent,root);
 }
 else
 {
 del_c(parent,root); //No child is NULL
 }
}

del_a(node **parent,node **root)
{
 if((*parent)->left==(*root))
 {
  free(*root);
  (*parent)->left=NULL;
 }
 else
 {
  free(*root);
  (*parent)->right=NULL;
 }
}

del_b(node **parent,node **root)
{
 if(((*parent)->left)==(*root))
 {
  if(((*root)->left)==NULL)
  {
   (*parent)->left=(*root)->right;
   free(*root);
  }
  else
  {
   (*parent)->left=(*root)->left;
   free(*root);
  }
 }
 else
 {
  if(((*root)->left)==NULL)
  {
   (*parent)->right=(*root)->right;
   free(*root);
  }
  else
  {
   (*parent)->right=(*root)->left;
   free(*root);
  }  
 }
}

del_c(node **parent,node **root)
{
 node *temp=(*root)->right;
 node *prt=(*root);
 while((temp->left)!=NULL)
 {
  prt=temp;
  temp=temp->left;
 }

  (*root)->data=temp->data;

 if((temp->right)==NULL)
 {
  del_a(&prt,&temp);
 }
 else
 {
  del_b(&prt,&temp);
 }

}
```

I am passing the arguments (where `head` is the first node)

```
delete(NULL,&head,n);
```

The program takes the number `n` to be deleted but then crashes immediately. What is the problem?

Comment: "crashes immediately" meaning what?  Seg fault?

Comment: I'm using windows console for running the program.It says 'the program stopped executing' and then prompts for a close

Answer (score 2):

You're using `parent` when it has an address of `NULL`.  You must be getting segmentation fault too.

Comment: so what should I pass as the arguments?

Comment: `parent` can't be `NULL`.  Do you have `parent` defined so you can call you function like this: `delete(&parent, &head, n);`?